# I am building a react native and I'm confused on how to display Trips in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

```
API:

app.get('/trip', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const employeeId = req.query.user;
    const empId = new ObjectID(employeeId);
    
    // Find the Fleet associated with the employee (driver) ID
    const fleet = await Fleet.findOne({ assignedDriverId: empId });

    if (!fleet) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Fleet not found for this employee' });
    }
  
    // Use the Fleet ID to find all trips assigned to this fleet (driver)
    const trips = await Trip.find({fleetAssignmentId:fleet._id})
    console.log("*********")
    console.log(trips)
   
    if (trips.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'No trips found for this driver' });
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Trips for the driver',
      trips: trips,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Internal Server Error',
      error: err.message,
    });
  }
});

Frontend:
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';


const App = () => {
  const [trips, setTrips] = useState([]);

  const fetchTrips = async (user) => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://192.168.4.4:5000/trip?user=${employeeId}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setTrips(data.trips);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTrips();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Trips</Text>
      {trips.map((trip) => (
        <Text key={trip.id}>{trip.tripName}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

*The Trip API is designed to handle query parameters for presenting trips in a React Native application. Users can pass specific parameters through the API to filter and retrieve relevant trip data, ensuring a tailored and seamless user experience in the React Native app. By leveraging these query parameters, the app can efficiently display the desired trips, enhancing user engagement and satisfaction.

Comment: This looks fine provided the data is coming back in the response, you are iterating through the data and rendering a text node per trip. Is there a problem you are having with the render or is this a generic data and architecture question?

Comment: Yes we have faced issue in rendering

Comment: Can you provide me Solution?

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question fully I would need more information on what the render error is.

#### Possible render issues

1. The data is not defined, so setting the trips value to undefined would crash the app. Add guards to the setTrips call such as `Array.isArray(data.trips)` would prevent setting state with the wrong type. The app is crashing due to the map method not existing on trips when it is set as something that is not an array.
2. The key of trip.tripName does not exist on the trips items. Confirm that by logging the data being iterated on.
3. Make sure the data response is being returned. And that the key trips is an array. Log the response. And make sure the server is actually returning data.

Recommendation:

- Switching to typescript would identify all these issues. Highly recommend doing this for both your nodejs server and react-native app.